# Show splash screen once using shared preferences

Tags: android

I have a screen that I want to show for the first time when my app loads. Then if you back out or hit the home screen, open the app again, I dont want the splash screen to show.

I tried to accomplish this by using shared preferences.

**When I run the app it shows the first screen. But then if I back out of it and open it back up it still shows the same screen.**

I tried by by setting a `Boolean` to true by default so it shows the screen. Then set it to false after being ran so the next time it runs through it will show main_activity.xml instead of splashscreen.xml

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();


        boolean firstTimeRun = getFirstTimeRun();

        if (firstTimeRun == true) {
            firstTimeRun();
        } else {
            run();
        }

        storeFirstTimeRun();

    }

    private boolean getFirstTimeRun() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("First Time Run Value", MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean firstTimeRun = prefs.getBoolean("firstRun", true);
        return firstTimeRun;
    }

    private void storeFirstTimeRun() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("First Time Run Value", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("first Run", false);
        editor.commit();
    }


    private void firstTimeRun() {
        setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
    }

    private void run() {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }


    public void CuFStudy(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Careunderfirestudy.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void TFCStudy(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Tacticalfieldcarestudy.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void TECStudy(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Tacticalevacuationcarestudy.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void CuFQuiz(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Careunderfirequiz.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void TFCQuiz(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Tacticalfieldcarequiz.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void TECQuiz(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Tacticalevacuationcarequiz.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both key is different which is used for retrieving and storing value in `SharedPreferences`.

Use `firstRun` as key in `storeFirstTimeRun`  method :

```
...
editor.putBoolean("firstRun", false);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: the ten minute timer kinda prevents that. i check back regularly. stop pressuring me!!!1